# Create new column with everything is between third - and forth - of another column

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I need to create a new column based on the column `col`, butextracting everything between the third `-` and the forth `-`. Examples:
`ABC-123-aaa-INEEDTHIS-2000-BBB-123-CCC`
`111-AAAAA-bb-INEEDTHIS-BB-435-A`

How can I do this with Big Query?
I'm trying something like this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(col, r'\w\w[^\d]\d\d') as newcol from mytable
```

I would like to understand too the `regex` behind this solution, if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

The simplest way is to use SPLIT function as in below example

```
SELECT SPLIT(col, '-')[SAFE_OFFSET(3)] AS newcol
```

If for some reason you want to go with regular expression - you can use REGEXP_EXTRACT as in below example

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(col, r'(?:[^-]*-){3}([^-]+)') AS newcol
```

You can test, play with both above approaches using sample data from your question as in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'ABC-123-aaa-INEEDTHIS-2000-BBB-123-CCC' col UNION ALL
  SELECT '111-AAAAA-bb-INEEDTHIS-BB-435-A'
)
SELECT 
  col, 
  SPLIT(col, '-')[SAFE_OFFSET(3)] AS newcol_with_split,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(col, r'(?:[^-]*-){3}([^-]+)') AS newcol_with_regexp
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with output

```
Row col                                     newcol_with_split   newcol_with_regexp   
1   ABC-123-aaa-INEEDTHIS-2000-BBB-123-CCC  INEEDTHIS           INEEDTHIS    
2   111-AAAAA-bb-INEEDTHIS-BB-435-A         INEEDTHIS           INEEDTHIS
```

Brief explanation for regexp

1. `[^-]*-` captures entries like `ABC-`, `123-`, aaa- etc.
2. `(?:[^-]*-)` makes sure those entries will not be extracted
3. `(?:[^-]*-){3}` makes sure first three such entries will be skipped
4. Finally, `([^-]+)` extracts target fragment till next `-`

Comment: Yes, you nailed it! Thanks! Do you know which one has better performance on big data?